# How to hide tab's body when tabs are minimized

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create JavaFX tabs which can be minimized and shrieked vertically. Something like this:

[image]

I only want to display the tab names and remove the body. Setting the vertical position of the tabs is easy:

```
tabPane.setSide(Side.RIGHT);
```

The problem is how I can remove the body of the tabs?

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

Tab tab0 = new Tab("blue");
tab.setContent(new Rectangle(200,200, Color.BLUE));

Tab tab1 = new Tab("green");
tab.setContent(new Rectangle(200,200, Color.GREEN));

tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab0, tab1);
```

Comment: tabPane.getTabs().clear()?

Comment: All tabs are removed, not only the body.